# "temporal" vs. "temporary"

Tags: synonyms

Is there any difference between the two?

In a technical document I have used a phrase "this is a temporal solution" and my coworker told that he'd use "temporary" in the context. Is one of the two more correct than the second?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Temporal* means “pertaining to time”. Personally I have not enountered this word in normal speech at all, even in somewhat formal writing. I have only encountered it as a technical term. For example, in grammar, the part of the sentence that specifies the time at which something happened (e.g. “today” or “throughout the year”) is a *temporal adverbial*. The word also comes up a lot in science-fiction wherever some made-up technical term pertaining to time (usually time travel) is required, e.g. *temporal mechanics*. In real science, the term is sometimes used as a complement to *spatial* (pertaining to space).

*Temporary* is a much more common word. It means “lasting for a limited time” and is the opposite of *permanent*. Politicians sometimes qualify their policies as a “temporary measure” to give the impression that there are plans for them to be repealed in due course (which, of course, never happens, but that’s a different matter).

**Edit:** In the specific example in your question, I think you most likely mean “a solution that isn’t permanent”, so *temporary* is definitely what you need. *Temporal* is wrong unless you are contrasting your solution against one that is *spatial* or in some other way not relating to time.

Comment: Would you say temporary/temporal/time sequence of events?

Answer (score 5):

- [temporal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temporal) means "of or relating to time as opposed to eternity"
- [temporary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temporary) means "lasting for a limited time"

One has no exact limit in time, the other comes with the definite notion of an expiration date.

- If you can say: "use this *for now*" (without specifying when you won't be able to use "this" anymore), "temporal" is fine.
- But if you can say: "use this until xxx", then "temporary" is the right choice.

That being said, I suspect there are many instances where one is being used instead of the other...

Comment: I think you are conflating the meanings of the two words even as you attempt to draw a distinction between them. There is functionally no difference between "using something for now" and using it "until xxx." *Temporal*, even in the definitions you cite, compares the finite to the infinite, which is a far cry from distinguishing between items having a specific expiration date and ones that do not.

Comment: I agree with Robusto. Both of your examples warrant use only of *temporary*. Just because something is used *for now*, doesn’t mean that this something *pertains or relates to time as opposed to eternity*.

Comment: @Robusto @Timwi: I agree about the conflation part. If temporal is to be used in place of temporary (like in "temporal solution"), then the distinction I make could be relevant. But both your explanations for temporal are much more to the point (and I have upvoted them).

Answer (score 5):

*Temporal* always refers to matters that are finite as opposed to infinite. You would not use it as just another synonym for *temporary*, even though it does mean that in a more specific way. It is more a synonym for *mortal* and usually refers to something involving the span of a human lifetime. It also is used to contrast human concerns with the religious or the divine. A bishop, for example, might speak of tending to the temporal needs of his flock to refer to the building of a hospital, since the repair of human bodies has nothing really to do with his principal duty of tending to their (supposedly) immortal souls.

Comment: Another synonim of temporal is "secular", as in "temporal power" (as opposed to the "religious power").

Answer (score 0):

Temporal refers more to a time relationship between two variables. "he started abusing alcohol after he lost his job" shows a "temporal", not "temporary" relationship between alcohol use and job loss. It kinds of establishes an association. I don't think its exactly synonymous to temporary.

Comment: Would you say temporary/temporal/time sequence of events?